# php string replacement performance

Tags: php, regex, performance, replace

I know it is generally suggested to avoid using regular expressions wherever possible, but what if there is a list of 20 or so characters you need to strip form a string?

Would it be more cost effective to do something like

```
$string = "...";

$a = array('a', '1', '!' ...);

foreach($a as $char){
    $string = str_replace($char, '', $string);

}
```

or would it be better to go with the regular expression

```
$string = preg_replace('#[a1!...]#', '', $string);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to loop through the array. Just use:    $string = str_replace($a, '', $string)

Comment: @redshark1802 has the right answer.

Comment: The answer to this, and almost all performance questions is invariably: test it!

Comment: If you perform this operation only a few times I think there are better things to optimize...

Comment: you can use `microtime()` with both options and see which runs faster: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 0):

First off `str_replace()` supports arrays for both the needle and the haystack so running it through a loop is just extra process.. Also I'd say in reply to regex vs string vs string. I'd go string to string in almost all cases. Regex can give false positives, and positive negatives. If not formulated correctly, and in such can become frustrating very quickly. Using it sparingly, also regex has adds more process as it has to match or not match something to the rule given. Where as string to string is if it matches it matches.

But this is just my opinion on the matter.